# How .to_day fixed my date issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

We have a build that runs all the ruby files including unit_tests.
Build is configured at UTC time and our database inserts records based on CST timezone because config.time_zone property in `application.rb` is set to CST timezone.

My unit tests had `start_date: 50.days.ago` and when i ran build it'll pass anytime during day before 7 PM. After 7 PM per build UTC time its next day. I mean if i start build at 7:10PM, build will show 12:10 AM and it'll fail.

I changed `start_date: 50.days.ago.to_date` and it doesnt fail now. 
Can someone explain me why it worked using `to_date`?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

`50.days.ago.to_date.class` it returns #ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

but when you do

`50.days.ago.class` it returns #Date

they feel the same but they are really different objects

Comment: Thanks I just remove the.to_date from the second one